# Tor is not connecting to the tor network it always gets stuck at 14%

Tags: tor

2/24/22, 00:49:27.531 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
2/24/22, 00:49:42.106 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
2/24/22, 00:49:42.107 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9150
2/24/22, 00:49:42.703 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay
2/24/22, 00:49:42.704 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay
2/24/22, 00:49:43.634 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 14% (handshake): Handshaking with a relay
2/24/22, 00:54:53.763 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 14% (handshake): Handshaking with a relay. (Connection refused [WSAECONNREFUSED ]; CONNECTREFUSED; count 10; recommendation warn; host CC701FCE86D6AF95FC3D5B71645D3430794910C1 at 157.90.183.103:9001)
2/24/22, 00:54:53.764 [WARN] 9 connections have failed:
2/24/22, 00:54:53.765 [WARN] 8 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
2/24/22, 00:54:53.765 [WARN] 1 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in CLOSED
2/24/22, 00:54:53.799 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
2/24/22, 00:54:53.799 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
2/24/22, 00:54:53.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 14% (handshake): Handshaking with a relay. (DONE; DONE; count 11; recommendation warn; host 3BB035514F8246AC367B5370F4FE120BB11D8C6D at 93.115.95.38:443)
2/24/22, 00:54:53.800 [WARN] 11 connections have failed:
2/24/22, 00:54:53.801 [WARN] 9 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
2/24/22, 00:54:53.801 [WARN] 1 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
2/24/22, 00:54:53.801 [WARN] 1 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in CLOSED
2/24/22, 00:54:53.804 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 14% (handshake): Handshaking with a relay. (DONE; DONE; count 12; recommendation warn; host 6D100EE20A83025E4005C655973FF59DF20D9218 at 185.216.72.133:443)
2/24/22, 00:54:53.804 [WARN] 12 connections have failed:
2/24/22, 00:54:53.805 [WARN] 9 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
2/24/22, 00:54:53.805 [WARN] 2 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
2/24/22, 00:54:53.805 [WARN] 1 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in CLOSED
2/24/22, 00:54:53.806 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 14% (handshake): Handshaking with a relay. (DONE; DONE; count 13; recommendation warn; host D52A160303C638D9FB03463F8A6B7934D5787F4C at 145.239.7.168:443)
2/24/22, 00:54:53.807 [WARN] 13 connections have failed:
2/24/22, 00:54:53.807 [WARN] 9 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
2/24/22, 00:54:53.807 [WARN] 2 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
2/24/22, 00:54:53.808 [WARN] 1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
2/24/22, 00:54:53.808 [WARN] 1 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in CLOSED
2/24/22, 00:54:53.810 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 14% (handshake): Handshaking with a relay. (DONE; DONE; count 14; recommendation warn; host 712E06F73325801AFC1836B2AFFFFC7CDF6BF939 at 46.183.217.3:443)
2/24/22, 00:54:53.810 [WARN] 15 connections have failed:
2/24/22, 00:54:53.810 [WARN] 10 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
2/24/22, 00:54:53.811 [WARN] 3 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
2/24/22, 00:54:53.811 [WARN] 1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
2/24/22, 00:54:53.812 [WARN] 1 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in CLOSED
2/24/22, 00:54:53.813 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 14% (handshake): Handshaking with a relay. (DONE; DONE; count 15; recommendation warn; host 2EB3C230180694A1E848001E20F36F76A2287039 at 62.210.123.24:443)
2/24/22, 00:54:53.813 [WARN] 16 connections have failed:
2/24/22, 00:54:53.814 [WARN] 10 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
2/24/22, 00:54:53.814 [WARN] 4 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
2/24/22, 00:54:53.815 [WARN] 1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
2/24/22, 00:54:53.815 [WARN] 1 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in CLOSED
2/24/22, 00:54:54.840 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
2/24/22, 00:54:54.434 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.

Hope the logs help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this link can solves your problem:

[DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/core/tor/-/issues/25713#:%7E:text=Tor%20will%20not%20make%20or,Shutting%20down%20all%20existing%20connections.&text=Now%2C%20Tor%20Browser%20legitimately%20starts,starts%20interacting%20with%20the%20network.)

welcome to the future.

Comment: Please refrain from posting link-only answers. Also note that the question itself is off-topic here.

Comment: Excuse me does the link doesn't solves your problem???

Comment: 1) this isn't my problem, but 2) link-only answers are not valid answers. And as I already mentioned on another answer of yours: you are answering questions that are off-topic for Stack Overflow. The question itself is not related to programming, and contains nothing but an output dump. If you insist on sharing only a link, it should go as a comment under the question (once you earn enough reputation), not as an answer.

Comment: I suggest reviewing [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) which provides more information. Also check out [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) which shows what questions are on- and off-topic, specifically "*Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.*"

Comment: Hahahahahahaha. Okay thank you. You get the point I'm looking for.